# Need sql server 2000 for win 7 64 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have SQL server 2000 dev edition. But it isn't compatible with my new win7 pro 64 bit computer. Is there a free version of 2000 that I can install on my 64 bit pc for development?

As I understand it, I can restore a 2000 database to sql server 2008. But I wont be able to restore the database back to the 2000 server after making any changes in 2008.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using a 10 year old piece of software for development?

Comment: @Chris: Maybe he has to support SQL Server 2000? If you have old application, you can't force all clients to move to newer version and you have to still test against it.

@Ronnie: You can make use of integrated XP Mode and install database there.

Comment: The number of breaking changes in moving from sql server 2000 to sql server 2005 is exceeding small.  I seriously doubt their app would have any problems all with the switch.  The only real reason not to update is cost.  But he's already using MSDE, meaning sql server 2005 express -- which is free -- should easily cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free version of sql server 2000 is called "MSDE".  I haven't tried it, but I don't think it works with windows 7.  If it does work with Windows 7, you'll have to make sure you run the installer as administrator, and remember that being logged in to the administrator account isn't enough to ensure that happens anymore.

Otherwise, you'll have to update to at least sql server 2005.  Both sql server 2005 and sql server 2008 have express editions with licenses that do permit production use if that's any help.  If that doesn't work you'll need to install sql server 2000 on a separate machine (even a vm would do) and use newer sql server management studio software to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a virtual pc or equivalent with an older OS image on it. I use Virtualbox, it's free and I am very happy with it. I always keep on my home server a compressed Virtualbox image of XP  with Sql Server for emergencies.

Answer (score 1):

step1

1-Enter gpedit.msc into the start menu and hit Enter.

2-Now navigate to User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Application Compatibility. Then on the left side under Setting double click on Turn off Compatibility Assistant.

3-Now click on Enabled then click on Apply and OK then close out of Local Group Policy Editor.

step2
go to services and disable Program Compatibility Assistant Service

step3
restart the pc

step4
go to SQL installation folder and choose edition .

Then run setup.bat

step5
please install sql 2000 sp4 when the installation is done.
NB do not run autorun.exe bc you will get error.

IT WILL WORK BC IT IS WORKING ON MY W7 MACHINE
Talley 
Raleigh,NC
talleyouro@hotmail.com
"The light will always dominate the darkness"